# Replace first character of string in loop

Tags: javascript, replace

On the page, the calendar columns are displayed with abbreviations, such as "sat" instead of "saturday".

```
<div class="dayClass">sat, 14 may</div>
<div class="dayClass">sun, 15 may</div>
<div class="dayClass">mon, 16 may</div>
```

to be like below

```
<div class="dayClass">Saturday, 14 may</div>
<div class="dayClass">Sunday, 15 may</div>
<div class="dayClass">Monday, 16 may</div>
```

I wrote this code by searching
But I can't just change the word "day" and the date will also be replaced

```
window.onload = function findAndReplaceDayName(){
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.dayClass');
for ( var i=elements.length; i--; ) {
  var text = elements[i].innerText;
   if(text.slice(0,3) == 'sat' ){
    elements[i].textContent = "Saturday"
  }else if(text.slice(0,3) == 'sun'){
elements[i].textContent = "Sunday";
    }else if(text.slice(0,3) == 'mon'){
elements[i].textContent = "Monday";
}}
```

But the result is this

```
<div class="dayClass">Saturday</div>
<div class="dayClass">Sunday</div>
<div class="dayClass">Monday</div>
```

Can you help me to change only the day and not the date.
**Thankful**
*Footnote: I am new to both programming and English language*

Comment: You can not just overwrite the `textContent` of the element with the day, you need to append the rest of the original text as well. `elements[i].textContent = "Sunday" + text.slice(4)`

Comment: Feels like you should change settings in your calendar library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.onload = function findAndReplaceDayName() {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.dayClass');
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var text = elements[i].innerText;
    if (text.indexOf(',') !== -1) {
      var dayName = text.slice(0, text.indexOf(',')).trim();
      var date = text.slice(text.indexOf(',') + 1).trim();
      switch (dayName) {
        case 'sat':
          dayName = 'Saturday';
          break;
        case 'sun':
          dayName = 'Sunday';
          break;
        case 'mon':
          dayName = 'Monday';
          break;
        // add more cases for other days if needed
      }
      elements[i].textContent = dayName + ', ' + date;
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate your **English** as well as **coding** though you are a beginner.

There's just a small change in your code that has to be made.
Like this :

```
window.onload = function findAndReplaceDayName(){
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.dayClass');
for ( var i=elements.length; i--; ) {
  var text = elements[i].innerText;
   if(text.slice(0,3) == 'sat' ){
     elements[i].textContent = "Saturday" + text.slice(3) // important
   }else if(text.slice(0,3) == 'sun'){
     elements[i].textContent = "Sunday" + text.slice(3) // important
   };
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

By writing  `elements[i].textContent = "Saturday"` you are replacing all of the textContent by 'Saturday'. That's why you lost all of the text.

You sould replace only the first characters. So, by writing
`elements[i].textContent = "Saturday"; elements[i].textContent += text.slice(3);` you'll replace all the text by Saturday then you'll add the next part to keep it.

Answer (score 0):

As many other answers point out: you should replace a part of the string, keeping the rest intact.

Personally I'd avoid hardcoding those numbers, and would attempt to get the first part of the string up to the comma instead. Also, for systematic replacement of a small set of things, an object or an actual [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) may be a good choice. And if you succumb to the dark side, [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) can do the entire thing, as it can look for a regular expression, and then provide a replacement dynamically based on its findings:

```js
const mapping = {
  "sat": "Saturday",
  "sun": "Sunday",
  "mon": "Monday"
};

function clicky() {
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.dayClass');
  for (const element of elements)
    element.textContent = element.textContent.replace(/[^,]+/, day => mapping[day]);
}
```

```html
<div class="dayClass">sat, 14 may</div>
<div class="dayClass">sun, 15 may</div>
<div class="dayClass">mon, 16 may</div>
<button onclick="clicky()">ClickMe</button>
```

Here the `[^,]+` matches the non-comma characters from the start of the string, and then this match is going to be the `day` argument for the arrow function, which simply looks up the corresponding long-name from the `mapping` object defined at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple method - I am assuming there is always a match in fullNames.

```js
const fullNames = { "sat":"Saturday","sun":"Sunday","mon":"Monday" };
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () =>  {
  document.querySelectorAll('.dayClass').forEach(div => {
    const text = div.textContent.slice(0,4);
    if (!text.endsWith(",")) return;
    div.innerText = fullNames[text.slice(0,3)] + div.innerText.slice(3);
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="dayClass">sat, 14 may</div>
<div class="dayClass">sun, 15 may</div>
<div class="dayClass">sun is shining today</div>
<div class="dayClass">mon, 16 may</div>
```

If there is no way dayClass can start with anything else but day abbreviations, the code is even simpler

```js
const fullNames = { "sat":"Saturday","sun":"Sunday","mon":"Monday" };
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () =>  {
  document.querySelectorAll('.dayClass').forEach(div => {
    const text = div.textContent.slice(0,3);
    div.innerText = fullNames[text] + div.innerText.slice(3);
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="dayClass">sat, 14 may</div>
<div class="dayClass">sun, 15 may</div>
<div class="dayClass">sun is shining today</div>
<div class="dayClass">mon, 16 may</div>
```